# jQuery saving string with .text() + JSON and reading with .val() loses line breaks

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, text, line-breaks

I'm sending and retrieving data to view it in a `<textarea>`.

**sending:**

```
$.ajax({
           url: "./xxx/xxx",
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "json",
           data: JSON.stringify({
           text: $('#txtText').text(),
           xxx: $('#xxx').text()
        })
```

**retrieving**

```
if (data.d.Text != "") {
        $('#txtText').val(data.d.Text);
}
```

The result is the correct text that was sent, but **without** line breaks. I need the line breaks displayed correctly.

I've played around with `.text()`, `.html()` and `.val()` but couldn't figured it out.

***I'm using jQuery 1.7.2***

Comment: At what point are you losing the line breaks?  `.val()` appears to preserve them quite happily in my own tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.val()` to retrieve the contents too, not `.text()`.

The latter will only retrieve the value that was in the page *as downloaded from the server*.

Any subsequent edits only alter the `.value` property of the field, and not the contents of the field's text node children.

Comment: @KeithL. p.s. see http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/j3BwS/ to see the difference in action.

Answer (score 0):

Add code to replace <br/> to new line \n character

```
text_str = data.d.Text
text_str = text_str.replace("<br/>","\n"); 
$('#txtText').val(text_str);
```

Comment: there are no `<br>` strings in the content of a textarea, at least not unless they've been explicitly typed in.